# MySQL condition on joined data

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have two tables "customers" and "campaigns":

```
    customers
    -------------
    id   | int
    -------------
    name | varchar 


    campaigns
    ----------------------
    id           | int
    ----------------------
    customers_id | int
    ----------------------
    name         | varchar
```

A customer can have multiple campaigns. The association between the two tables is via `campaigns.customers_id = customers.id`.
Now I want to get all customers that have gotten campaign with name "A" and name "B".

I tried a `JOIN` with an `IN` statement, but it returns all customers, that have received any of campaign "A" or "B":

```
    SELECT
      customers.name
    FROM
      customers
    JOIN
      campaigns
    ON
      customers.id=campaigns.customers_id
    WHERE
      campaigns.name IN('A','B')
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You've joined on the wrong columns. Also... Group by ... having count(*) = n -- where n is no. of items in IN() (assuming (customer,campaign) is UNIQUE

Comment: Strawberry: Thanks for pointing the column names out. You're right, edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to join for each campaign

```
SELECT
  customers.name
FROM
  customers
INNER JOIN campaigns c1 ON customers.id=c1.id and c1.name = 'A'
INNER JOIN campaigns c2 ON customers.id=c2.id and c2.name = 'B'
```

This will now contain customers who have received both.

Comment: Yes, good update, but instead of just writing queries, it better helps people to know what and why you did something.  Maybe clarification to  why double-join and why your original answer was incorrect via left-join.  People who are just GIVEN answers don't learn and become script copiers. (just constructive criticism... I too started early with simpler answers).

Comment: This solution isn't very scalable.

Answer (score 1):

You have joined campaigns table with `customers.id=campaigns.id` instead of `customers.id=campaigns.customers_id`.

Correct Query is

```
SELECT
      customers.name
    FROM
      customers
    JOIN
      campaigns
    ON
      customers.id=campaigns.customers_id
    WHERE
      campaigns.name IN('A','B')
```

This should work :)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my question. I have joined the right columns , using IN gives me all customers that have campaign "A" or "B", but I want all customers that have both campaigns.

Comment: SELECT
      customers.name
    FROM
      customers
    JOIN
      campaigns
    ON
      customers.id=campaigns.customerid
    WHERE
      campaigns.name LIKE 'A' OR campaigns.name LIKE 'B' GROUP BY customers.id; It should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  customers.name
FROM
  customers
LEFT JOIN campaigns c1 ON customers.id=c1.customers_id and c1.name = 'A'
LEFT JOIN campaigns c2 ON customers.id=c2.customers_id and c2.name = 'B'
```

With the first LEFT JOIN you will get the customers that have campaigns and the campaign names are 'A', and then the result will join with the campaigns whose have name 'B'.

Only the rows with `campaign.name = A` and `campaign.name = B` will be selected.

Comment: I don't know why this answer has been downvoted. Can anyone explain me?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Dunno about the downvotes. When I change "LEFT JOIN" to "INNER JOIN" it returns the expected results.